# How to keep only groups above certain number of rows?

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

data<-diamonds%>%group_by(cut,color,clarity)%>%
  summarize(aver=round(mean(price),0),count=n())%>%
  filter(count>10)%>%
  mutate(rank1=min_rank(desc(aver)),rank2=cume_dist(desc(aver)))
```

So when you run this script you will get output below. Now in cut and color column there are just 3 combinations " Fair D" which is also possible to see from rank1 column. Another group " Fair E" has 5 rows. I want to keep just rows for groups with more than 3 rows .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `filter` with a logical condition (`n() > 3`) to keep only groups that have number of rows greater than a particular value

```
data %>% 
     filter(n()>3)
```